# JSOM context newly created id reference when creating more than one item

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model

I am using the COM JavaScript/jQuery to get, create & update some list items. I have two lists and every time I create a new item in one list, the newly created id is something that I want to grab in order to place in a FK like field in the second list (not even using linked at this point, just a generic integer type field).

Simple enough, but what if I want to through this process into a loop and create 10 at the same time.

after I create a new item using

```
function createItem(tbl, obj, callback) {
    var cxt = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = cxt.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(list);
    var createInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.listItem = list.addItem(createInfo);
    for ( var prop in obj ) {
        listItem.set_item(prop, obj[prop]) 
    }
    cxt.load(listItem);
    cxt.executeQueryAsync(callback, Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

_createItem ('ListA', { Title: 'First List Item' }, function () {
      var thisId = listItem.get_id();
      var other = {
           Title: 'Second List Item',
           RelatedId: thisId
      };
      _createItem('ListB', other, function () {
           console.log('created');
      });
});
```

When I use the above inside a loop to create 5 records in both lists it doesn't work, the `thisId/item.get_()` typically returns a -1 even though the items are getting created in both lists. I am sure there is a perfectly good reason this occurs, I am just unsure of it and was hoping someone could help me understand, and perhaps if there is a way to get at what I am trying to do properly. I have tried deep copies and this doesn't seem to matter?

Answer (score 0):

Due to *async* nature of JSOM I would recommend [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065175/1375553).

The example demonstrates how to create multiple list items using JSOM:

```
//Create multiple contact items using Named Function Expressions (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065175/1375553)
var createContactItems = function createContactItem(i,itemsCount)
{
    createListItem('Contacts',contactProperties,
     function(item) {
          console.log('Contact have been created');        
          var nextItemId = item.get_id() + 1;
          contactProperties.Title = 'Doe' + nextItemId;
          if(i <  itemsCount) {
               createContactItem(i+1,itemsCount);
          }
     },
     function logError(sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
     }
   );
}

var numberOfContacts = 10;
createContactItems(0,numberOfContacts);
```

where

```
function createListItem(listTitle,itemProperties,success,error)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    for(var propName in itemProperties) {
       listItem.set_item(propName, itemProperties[propName]) 
    }
    listItem.update();
    context.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
          success(listItem);
      },
      error);
}
```